# cin.getline(char, int) gets skipped when in a loop

Tags: c++, getline, turbo-c++

This is the code I have been trying to execute on TurboC++ 3.0 (Yes, I know it's ancient but can't help it), when the program goes into the loop, it skips the value of y every time including the first attempt. Any help would be appreciated but please avoid rubbing salt into wounds by asking why TurboC++ 3.0. Thanks in advance.

```
void main()
{
    int x, z;
    char y[10];
    for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        cout<<"\nX:";
        cin >> x;
        cout<<"\nY:"; 
        cin.getline(y,10); 
        cout<<"\nZ:";
        cin>>z;
    }
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        cout<<x<<"\n"; 
        cout.write(y, 10)<<"\n";
        cout<<z<<"\n\n";
    }
}
```

and even if I use cin.get(var) where var is a character, i still get weird results like a heart, diamond or even a smiley.

Comment: You could at least indent the code properly :(

Answer (score 0):

You get weird results because you are not terminating your c style string with a null character.('\0').
The problem you are facing is because , fail bit or eof bit is set.  To remove that, do the following:-

You can use

```
  cin.clear() ;
```

to clear if any error bits are set and then use

```
cin.ignore(100, '\n') ; 
// 100 is just a random no, change it depending on your size of input.
```

to ignore any irrelevant characters int the stream.

or you can do the following:-

after `cin>>x`   just type `cin.ignore()`, it will flush out any newline characters present in the buffer .

Answer (score 0):

> it skips the value of y

`cin >> x` reads the input until it finds something that's not a digit - in this case, the end-of-line character. That character is left in the stream.

`getline` reads the input until it finds an end-of-line character (or the end of the stream). Since you've left one in the stream, it finds it straight away and doesn't read anything.

You can call `cin.ignore(-1,'\n')` to ignore the remainder of the first line after reading `x` (assuming your prehistoric library behaves like the modern one).

> i still get weird results like a heart, diamond or even a smiley

`cout.write(y, 10)` is wrong - there are up to 9 valid characters in `y`, followed by the null terminator. You want `cout << y` to treat it as a null-terminated string and print only the valid characters.

Comment: I understood your point about **cout.write()** being wrong, but what is the solution for it?

Comment: @user2529412: As I said, `cout << y`

Comment: **cin.ignore(-1,'\n')** skips the input for y. It jumps to next input for x and displays shapes and the last given input for x.

Comment: @0x499602D2: I said "end-of-line" (or "newline" if you like) not EOF. `-1` converts to the maximum value of the (unsigned) `streamsize` type. `y` is null terminated, since `getline` terminates it.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Right, I get my wording mixed up sometimes. And I was thinking about `std::getline` not `std::istream::getline`. +1